# android get the letters in a certain range

Tags: android

I trying a make word hunt game in Android. User draw line in  word hunt puzzle. I got the coordinate of line. The puzzle has 100 letters. The hidden words are in below puzzle. User need show words with line. I got the coordinate of letters. Now I need to see which letters it passes over with the corrdinates. But I don’t know how to make.

I eşit for ideas, suggestions or suggestions for code.

I need your help.